# Force TortoiseSVN to show error messages in english

Tags: svn, error-handling, localization, tortoisesvn

Today I tried to commit into SVN and Tortoise failed. Its error message is in portuga (`svn error running context nenhuma conexão pode ser feita porque a máquina de destino as recusou ativamente`) and it's VERY hard to search for a solution.

So, before I can search for a solution, I need first to make it properly report the error.

Settings > General > Language is already set as English.

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: What's your system language / LOCALE?

Comment: What language do you see when you run `svn.exe` client?

Comment: Unfortunately, Windows locale is pt-BR. When I run svn.exe it's in english.

Comment: I'm not sure how to switch this in TortoiseSVN, but you could ask at TortoiseSVN users@ mailing list https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/tortoisesvn FYI: the list is premoderated.

Comment: If svn.exe shows messages in english, maybe that error message is coming from Windows?

Comment: google translator says this means connection error. So check firewall settings maybe the SVN server is blocked.